# Mission control + spotlight

Tags: macos, spotlight, mission-control

I am coming from linux world, using plain gnome.
In gnome there is a view very similar to mission control:
[image: gnome]
The main difference is that gnome has a "search" field (which in essence is like Spotlight).

I would like to have the same kind of view on my Mac.
Is there an app which could replace mision control and provide something closer to gnome?

Comment: Why can't you just use Spotlight directly from Finder?

Comment: @nohillside I use spotlight with CMD+Space already but I found handy to have it in mission control as well. In one go I can look at which apps are open, and I can open a new one.

Comment: I have the same issue, gnome is 10x more usable than macos :(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can install Gnome on MacOS with MacPorts.

https://ports.macports.org/port/gnome-desktop/

I have not tried this myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something like [Mission Control](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh35798/mac) but with a Spotlight search bar, I don't think that's possible yet.

Pressing Spotlight's keyboard shortcut (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) exits Mission Control to open Spotlight instead.

It seems that ***those two features aren't compatible***.

---

That's not perfect for what you asked but you can use Launchpad, it's about the same but the only thing is that it doesn't show opened windows, just apps as does iPhone's or iPad's Home Screens. It also contains a search bar for you to search between apps. (See [Use Launchpad to view and open apps on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-apps-with-launchpad-mh35840/mac) for more information and guidance)

[image: Screenshot taken on macOS Ventura of the Launchpad]